# How long would a camera battery last unused?

Tags: canon, battery, camera, powershot

I discovered an old camera (canon powershot a3300 is if it helps) that i stopped using about 8-10 years ago. I lost the battery charger but found one online that i could buy. Just wanted to know if its still possible that the battery works or if i should also buy another battery.

Comment: It's possible that it will work, and also possible that it won't -- buy the charger and try it, if the battery won't charge, then buy a new one. There's not much point in asking the internet if some 10 year old battery will work, no one can tell you for sure -- but you can.

Answer (score 7):

> Just wanted to know if its still possible that the battery works or if i should also buy another battery.

**Yes, and yes.**

Yes, it's possible that the battery still works -- I've been able to charge original batteries from my circa 2005 Rebel XT after they've sat for years, although the performance isn't nearly as good as new. But you won't really know unless you try it.

And yes, you should buy another battery if you plan to use the camera. Third party NB-8L batteries that fit that camera are cheap -- you can find kits with two batteries and a charger for as little as $13 including shipping. So it doesn't make a lot of sense to buy a charger alone and hope that your 10yo battery is still in good shape. Buy a kit that includes a charger and at least one new battery, and if the old one happens to still take a decent charge then you'll have one more spare.

Answer (score 1):

The battery will most likely work, but may need a few charges/discharged before reaching it's best possible performance.
I wouldn't expect the capacity to be as good as it were 8-10 years ago though, but it should be usable.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether it is second-source or original.  Second-source batteries tend to save on materials in quality and quantity, leading to quite higher self-discharge rates and self-corrosion even in storage.

In contrast, storing original Li+ based batteries at about half-charge in a reasonably cool and dry place tends to be comparatively benign.  After all, original batteries are planned with a potential quite higher stock and shelf life than typical second-source batteries are, and the effects of storage after light use are not all that much different from before it.

Answer (score 1):

The usual life of Li-ion batteries is only two to five years, even if they are sitting on a shelf unused. For this time batteries discharge (if not in use) from self-discharge current and they can't be reactivated. The situation can become worse if the place where you store them is hot.

For more information you can check for example [here](https://electronics.howstuffworks.com/everyday-tech/lithium-ion-battery2.htm).

IMO will be better to buy new battery, I saw them on Amazon for less than 15 USD

Comment: This is essentially wrong. Li-Ion batteries do age, even if not used, but they don't 'die' as you and the linked article claim. I have been using 10+ years old Li-Ion batteries on older equipment without any other problem than capacity loss. For older equipment, it is often the only way to still use it, since fresh, proprietary batteries are often not available at all.

Comment: @jarnbjo, OK, let wait for feedback from OP

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes they survive such long storage, sometimes they do not. Fact is, practically all rechargeable Li-Ion packs that are sold to the general public and can be installed without tools have a trapdoor circuit inside that permanently disables the battery once it reaches deep discharge. The exception might be dodgy third-party packs. Leaving that circuit out, or defeating it (there are tutorials on the web suggesting overloading that circuit to fuse it short - DON'T!), is not a feature but criminal madness - attempting to charge that battery risks blowing it sky high.